# Mi programa crashea al concluir

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo a programar C++ y he escrito el siguiente codigo. Todo corre bien pero al final (cuando se admite el decimo valor) deja de funcionar.
Estoy usando MSVC2015.

Me pueden ayudar con esto, por favor?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int pank[10];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        cout << "Cuantos pancakes se comio la persona No." << i << " " << endl;
        cin >> pank[i];
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Eso se debe a que los arrays empiezan por la posición 0. Es decir, si tu array tiene que tener 10 posiciones tendrá las posiciones:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 y 9
```

Por tanto, en tu bucle tienes que ir desde la posición `0` a la posición `n-1 (10-1 = 9)`. Tendrías que cambiar la condición tal que así:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                 ^^
   cout << "Cuantos pancakes se comio la persona No." << i << " " << endl;
   cin >> pank[i];
}
```

El error que te da se debe a que si pones la condición `i<=10` también va a intentar almacenar un valor para la posición `10` del array, la cual no existe.

Va a intentar hacer esto:

```
cin >> pank[10];
```

lo cual es erróneo ya que esa posición no existe y por eso tienes que indicar en la condición que recorra hasta el número `n-1`.